# Video player with play/pause controls and pictureInPicture like in Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios9

How can I use a video player like this screenshot and include it in my **Objective-C** application:

[image]

I took it in Safari on iPad air2 simulator with IOS9, and it was playing a live broadcast ..

It looks like **MPMoviePlayerViewController** but it is formally deprecated in iOS 9 ..

Also doesn't look like **AVPictureInPictureController** or **AVPlayerViewController** because they don't have any control buttons ..

So, I'm asking how can I include in my app such player (contain done/play/pause/pictureInPicture) buttons and is supported in IOS9

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Did you try `AVPlayerViewController` with `showsPlaybackControls
 = YES`, `allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = YES` to show playbacks control and PiP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot to [Luan Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5352548/luan-nguyen) ..

I was able to include the player from the screenshot in my application using **AVPlayerViewController** and `showsPlaybackControls = YES, allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = YES`

Here is the full **sample code** :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>

@interface ViewController ()<AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate>{
    AVPlayerViewController *_AVPlayerViewController;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

    // create a movie player
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://38.96.175.119:1935/aletejahtv/aletejahtv3/playlist.m3u8"];

    _AVPlayerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
    _AVPlayerViewController.delegate = self;
    _AVPlayerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
    _AVPlayerViewController.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = YES;
    _AVPlayerViewController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    _AVPlayerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    [_AVPlayerViewController.player play];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self presentViewController:_AVPlayerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}

@end
```